# Google App Engine Flexible C# Connection to Cloud SQL SQL Server problem when deploying

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, google-cloud-sql, app-engine-flexible

I have this problem when trying to deploy to AppEngine. On local machine using proxy it works fine.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'dblivtron' on server 'cloudsql'.

My config:

```
Appengine Flexible API = enabled
Cloud SQL Admin API = enabled
Instance public address = enabled

Instance Connection Name: livtron-testproject:europe-west1:livtrondbinstance
Database: dblivtron
```

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: livtron-testproject:europe-west1:livtrondbinstance=tcp:3306'
```

My connection string in appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=cloudsql;Database=dblivtron;User Id=sqlserver;Password=#####;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=false;Pooling=true;"
  }
```

Comment: On your app.yaml you're using port `3306`. Have you tried using the default TCP port `1433`?

Comment: I would try SQL Server management Studio on remote machine and see if you can make the connection.  The Server is usually server/instance.  Using SSMS will give much better error messages.

Comment: Could you share your full ["CloudSQL"](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/CloudSql/appsettings.json) from your appsettings, hiding sensitive info?

Comment: 3306 is in GCP documentation. There's nothing else about "CloudSQL" in appsettings.  Its's a host name in GCP. I was able to connect to the remote database throught proxy using SSMS. Only during deploy I had an error.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the error I was getting was a little misleading. I worked when I removed `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` from connectionstring. I had to correct my code as well to help the MARS problems in aplication. But now it works.